# Visualforce Page to access an Opportunity's PriceBook

Tags: apex, visualforce, developer-console, console

I am trying to develop a custom Button on Opportunity which will open 
VF page showing all PriceBook (picklist) which we can select on clicking any on of them.
Any help would be very much appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: Can you post your code whatever you have tried so far

Comment: Hi Santanu I have posted my code in Answer Please check it.
But it's not complete.

Answer (score 0):

As I am new to salesforce. I am not able to complete this case. here is my code. –
Controller:
public class Opportunity_PriceBookPageExtension {

```
private final Opportunity opp;
public string selectedPricebook {get;set;}
public List<SelectOption> PricebookOptions{get;set;}


public Opportunity_PriceBookPageExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {

    this.opp = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
    List<Pricebook2> pricebooks = [SELECT Id, Name from Pricebook2 where IsActive = true];
    system.debug('====>>>>PriceBook'+pricebooks);

}


public List<SelectOption> getPricebookOptions() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    List<Pricebook2> pricebooks = [SELECT Id, Name from Pricebook2 where IsActive = true];
    system.debug('====>>>>PriceBook in Method'+pricebooks);
    for(Pricebook2 pricebook : pricebooks) {
    options.add(new SelectOption(pricebook.Id,pricebook.Name));
    }
return options;
}
```

}